# Removed my wsl-installer and now can't access or reinstall at all

Tags: c, linux, windows, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Im now getting the following error whenever I try to do anything wsl related:

The system cannot find the file specified.
Error code: Wsl/CallMsi/ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

As far as I know there is no way to redownload wsl without having access to it already.
Did this in order to fix some previous wsl error that didn't go away.

Is there any way I can get it back without a full windows reinstall

I can't seem to find anyone with a similiar issue online, and all fixes seem to require wsl on the system.

Comment: Can you provide an example of something "wsl related" that you specifically do? Perhaps also a description of the exact steps you took to remove your wsl-installer

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.